# Dataproc to Databricks migration - Permissions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, google-cloud-dataproc

currently migrating pyspark jobs from GCP dataproc to databricks. We are using 3 different GCP projects to test the migration.

- Project-1: Holds production data which is to be read
- Project-2: Existing Code base is running here on Dataproc, with all relevant permissions
- Project-3: New Project created for Databricks , which leverages Service account permission from Project-2 to read data present in Project-1. The Service account tagged to Databricks cluster has relevant permissions to access Service Account from Project-2, which in-turn has read access to data in Project-1. The Service account tagged to Databricks cluster has no direct access to data in project-1, instead has to leverage permissions from SA of Project-2, handled part of code.

We have below configuration in existing code:

```
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.gs.project.id", "<val>")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.email", "<val>")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id", "<val>"])
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key", "<val>")
```

we have a method-1 which calls another method-2 to check if files exists, if file available on cloud storage, method-1 reads data as dataframe.

Method-1: read_data

```
def read_data(self,spark):
    valid_paths = self.filter_valid_paths(self.paths(),spark,<..other params..>)
    dataframe = spark.read("read the above valid_paths file")
```

Method-2: filter_valid_paths

```
def filter_valid_paths(self,paths,spark,<..other params..>):

        conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
        for k, v in spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll():
            if k.startswith("fs."):
                conf.set(k, v)

        for p in paths:
            path = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(p)
            fs = path.getFileSystem(conf)
            if fs.exists(path): # failing here, if filter_valid_paths() is invoked, else succeeds
                valid_paths.append(p)
            else:
                logger.info(f"ignoring invalid path: {p}")
        return valid_paths
```

**Issue**: The above code works fine in GCP Dataproc. However fails in databricks with message `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found` . Tried adding Google cloud storage connector for Spark and Hadoop as dependency, didnt work.  Hence I commented below 4 files in the config.

```
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
```

**Question**:
With above change, If I run the job, run fails with message that  service account tagged to databricks cluster does not have permission to read data. The databricks service account not having direct access to data in project-1 is expected, given we deliberately didnt provide direct permission, instead wanted to leverage permissions from Service account of Project-2.

However, if we comment the line invoking method-2 ie. filter_valid_paths in method-1 read_data(), I'm able to read the data, job succeeds in Databricks. Curious to know, if we dont invoke method-2 job succeeds ie job is referring to credentials from Project-2, however if we invoke method-2, the method-2 is trying to access SA tagged to Databricks instead of Project-2 credentials and failing.

Comment: May I ask about the reasons of the migration? Any problem with Dataproc?

Comment: all good with dataproc, it was for a different reason.